# Is it possible to reduce background noise while streaming audio on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, skype, webrtc

We used some `WebRTC libraries` and implemented them in a test app on the `iPhone`. The test app allows voice calls between two phones using this app, similar to Skype.

The app is picking up a lot of background noise, a lot more than Skype or other phone apps like Line.

Is there a way we can reduce the background noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you still get background noise if you use WebRTC lib and enabled NS option.

for me I build the standalone module of WebRTC noise suppression, and it works just fine. when using the most aggressive mode of NS instance, there is little background noise on both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Skype has its own codec with built in acoustic echo cancellation and noise suppression. There are also built in noise reduction mechanisms in iOS but there is no way to get around having your own codec which will perform such an action if you are looking to completely eliminate that noise. WebRTC is not there yet from that perspective.