# Open source codecs to reduce/minimize background noise or do echo cancellation?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, codec, echo-cancellation

This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845564/is-it-possible-to-reduce-background-noise-while-streaming-audio-on-the-iphone) of ours.

Are there any open source codec that can reduce/eliminate background noise?

In general, what are the most reliable or most popular codecs for echo cancellation?

Answer (score 2):

[Speex](https://www.speex.org/) (a free and open source codec) has a DSP library which provides echo cancellation, see [SpeexEchoState: Acoustic Echo Canceller](http://www.speex.org/docs/api/speex-api-reference/group__SpeexEchoState.html) (AEC). It can be used separately from the codec.

And [there is WebRTC](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/list) which comes with AEC code; that code base is used in PulseAudio to provide echo cancellation